# buy and sell order not working properly mql5

Tags: mql5

```
Hi I want to open and close buy/sell trades based on Moving Average. But here the problem is once the trade is opened its not closing based on my condition. Please assist on my below codes
```

The doubt which I have in the function buyOrderclose() and the function sellOrderclose(). I have checked my conditions looks pretty good and the buyOrder() and sellOrder() also. I have tested in Mql5 also but its not working properly

```
#include<Trade\Trade.mqh>
CTrade trade;

input double   lots=0.01;
double openCandle = iOpen(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,0);
double closeCandle = iClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,0);
double Balance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE);
double Equity = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_EQUITY);
int period = 10;
int EMA = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,period,0,MODE_EMA,0);

void OnTick()
  {
   buyOrder();
   sellOrder();
   buyOrderclose();
   sellOrderclose();
  }

void buyOrder()
  {
   if(openCandle < closeCandle)
      if(closeCandle < EMA)
         if(PositionsTotal() == 0)
           {
            double Ask = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);
            trade.Buy(lots,_Symbol,Ask,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            Print("BUY ORDER PLACED");
           }
     }

void sellOrder()
  {
   if(openCandle > closeCandle)
      if(closeCandle < EMA)
         if(PositionsTotal() == 0)
           {
            double Bid = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID),_Digits);
            trade.Sell(lots,_Symbol,Bid,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            Print("SELL ORDER PLACED");
           }
  }

void buyOrderclose()
  {
   if(openCandle > closeCandle)
      if(closeCandle < EMA)
        {
         // count until there are no positions left
         for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
           {
            //Get the ticket number for the currect position
            int ticket=PositionGetTicket(i);
            //Get the position direction
            int PositionDirection = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
            //if it is buy postition
            if(PositionDirection==POSITION_TYPE_BUY)
               //close the currect position
               trade.PositionClose(ticket);
           }
        }
  }

void sellOrderclose()
  {
   if(openCandle < closeCandle)
      if(closeCandle < EMA)
        {
         // count until there are no positions left
         for(int i=PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
           {
            //Get the ticket number for the currect position
            int ticket=PositionGetTicket(i);
            //Get the position direction
            int PositionDirection = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
            //if it is buy postition
            if(PositionDirection==POSITION_TYPE_SELL)
               //close the currect position
               trade.PositionClose(ticket);
           }
        }
  }
```

Please assist on this bot.. thanks in advance

```
Hi I want to open and close buy/sell trades based on Moving Average. But here the problem is once the trade is opened its not closing based on my condition. Please assist on my below codes
```

The doubt which I have in the function buyOrderclose() and the function sellOrderclose(). I have checked my conditions looks pretty good and the buyOrder() and sellOrder() also. I have tested in Mql5 also but its not working properly

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

1. you are **executing** all 4 custom function, in **each mili sec**. ( because you put it onTick() function. 
   **you code** is opening **buy, sell** and closing them too.. in every sec.

**SOLUTION**

1. put a **if else** condition in onTick(); funtion

if a condition met, e.g if the last candle close price is above the ema it will buy, and if there is any profit of 1$ close it. or close it by default stop loss

**IMAGINE THE FAKE CODE**

```
onTick(){

if ( close_price > ema )
    {
    buy();
    }
if ( close_price < ema )
   {
    sell();
   }
if ( profit == 0.50 ) 
   { 
    close_all();
   }
}
```

ARE YOU STILL CONFUSED???